# Does keeping reference to an ImageView Inside an Activity leaks whole Activity?

Tags: android

I've downloaded an ImageLoader library which asynchronously load image to image views. As I checked out the source code I found it keep a reference to each ImageView added until the image is loaded. Does this reference leak the whole Activity?

Comment: This depends on where the object which keeps reference to the `ImageView` is initialized. If within the activity? Then the answer is no (circular references are not leaks..) Also should not be static references

Comment: check this http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/. Quoting from the blog a reference to an activity should have the same life cycle as the activity itself

Comment: @AmulyaKhare yes, the imageView is initialized and is in queue for loading.

Comment: Are you talking about `volley`? then there is no memory leak..

Comment: You may create a WeakReference to it and see when it actually gets garbage-collected.

Comment: You said _it keep a reference to each ImageView_. What is `it`? If this `it` class object is init within the activity (&& is not static) then no memory leak..

Comment: Hmmm, the _ImageView_ constructors all include the parameter _Context context_, so it does keep a reference to the activity.

Comment: And the library obviously does keep a reference to the _ImageView_ whose image is being loaded.

Comment: You may try to print the result of _someImage.getContext()_ to the log. If it is the activity, then definitely yes. But that is not really a leak, the image will get loaded sooner or later. :)

Comment: Yes, it's leaking the activity. But does this leak ends when images are loaded?

Comment: It should. Try the WeakReference trick.